# How to add Dynamic label inside UIScrollView in ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview

Hierarchy of a `ViewController`

```
ScrollView 
    |_ _ UIView (Height and width equal to its superView)
                  |_ _ UIView (Set Height to 150 and I put a label inside this view and set number of lines to 0)
                  |_ _ UIView (Align bottom to top view with the height of 150)
```

If I keep the `label.text` too much then it's going behind the bottom view like this:

[image]

How can I keep the constant vertical distance between the second view and first view? So that it won't distort the UI. I want to achieve this

[image]

The approach I am using won't work because I am providing the fixed height for both `UIView`. Is there any way that we can handle the dynamic length of `label` in a `UIScrollView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ScrollView 
    |_ _ UIView (Height and width equal to its superView)
                  |_ _ UIView (Set Height to greater than or equal 150 and I put a label inside this view and set number of lines to 0)
                  |_ _ UIView (Align bottom to top view with the height of 150)
```

[image: Below are the constraints set to the view]
[image: View in the Storyboard]

the view reduces to a standard value of 150 according to the text of the label

[image: view reduced to standard value]

Comment: Have you tried after reducing the label content and How is it looking? Does it reduce the height of the first view as well?. If yes, Please paste the screenshot

Comment: Yes..the view reduces to a standard value of 150 (your needed requirement) according to the text in the label.

Comment: How did you give the margin between two views?

Comment: Go to Editor tab in Xcode --> Canvas --> Show Bounds rectangles

Comment: Totally slipped my mind that height of UIView was fixed. Setting it to greater than helped. Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set higher content compression resistance priority to UILabel. It'll prevent to setting label view size smaller than it intrinsic content size.